# Error installing Spring STS with Eclipse Mars

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, spring-tool-suite

Just installed latest 64 bit Mars j2ee Eclipse.

Went to marketplace to install Spring STS plugns.

Got the following error:

[image]

Comment: What update sites where you letting it search?

Comment: I double-checked the install of STS 3.7.2 from the Marketplace into a plain fresh Eclipse-Mars.1-JEE package and it works fine. Maybe you have the main Eclipse update site disabled in the preferences so that the install procedure can't find the zest component?